# How can I adjust the position of marginnote? (A \newcommand question)

Tags: environments, footnotes, marginnote, renewcommand

I have a small script that lets me have footnotes in the margin. It works as I want it, except that sometimes it overlaps, or if it's near the bottom of a page, the note will be clipped. Using the marginnote package, there is a built in height-adjustment like so: `\marginnote[2cm]`. This doesn't work with the script below. Can someone help me fix this?

```
\documentclass{article}
% ----- General page-settings ----- %
\usepackage[
    top=3cm,
    bottom=3cm, 
    outer=7cm, 
    marginparsep=1cm, 
    headsep=10pt,a4paper, 
    marginparwidth=4cm]{geometry} % Page margins

% Margin notes w. footnotes and math
\usepackage{marginnote}

% --- This whole thing gives footnotes in margin w. 
\newcounter{mgncount}
\renewcommand\themgncount{\arabic{mgncount} }
\newcommand\marginfoot[1]{\refstepcounter{mgncount}\marginnote{{$^{\themgncount}$}#1}\footnotemark}

\begin{document}
Here's some text \marginfoot{A footnote}
\end{document}
```

I tried adding a `[]` at the end of the `\renewcommand`-line, but it doesn't work. Appriciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want overlapping just use LaTeX's build in `\marginpar` instead of `\marginnote`.

```
\documentclass{article}
% ----- General page-settings ----- %
\usepackage[
    top=3cm,
    bottom=3cm, 
    outer=7cm, 
    marginparsep=1cm, 
    headsep=10pt,a4paper, 
    marginparwidth=4cm]{geometry} % Page margins

% --- This whole thing gives footnotes in margin w. 
\newcounter{mgncount}
\renewcommand\themgncount{\arabic{mgncount} }
\newcommand\marginfoot[1]{\refstepcounter{mgncount}\marginpar{{$^{\themgncount}$}#1}\footnotemark}

\begin{document}
Here's some text\marginfoot{A footnote}.\marginfoot{A second footnote}
\end{document}
```

[image: using \marginpar instead of \marginnote]

Pinning a note to exactly the line, where it is placed in the text, is one of the main features if `marginnote`.

However, if you really, really want to use `marginnote` (a package without any support), you can add an optional argument to your command:

```
\documentclass{article}
% ----- General page-settings ----- %
\usepackage[
    top=3cm,
    bottom=3cm, 
    outer=7cm, 
    marginparsep=1cm, 
    headsep=10pt,a4paper, 
    marginparwidth=4cm]{geometry} % Page margins

\usepackage{marginnote}
    
% --- This whole thing gives footnotes in margin w. 
\newcounter{mgncount}
\renewcommand\themgncount{\arabic{mgncount} }
\newcommand\marginfoot[2][0pt]{\refstepcounter{mgncount}\marginnote{{$^{\themgncount}$}#2}[#1]\footnotemark}

\begin{document}
Here's some text\marginfoot{A footnote}.\marginfoot[\baselineskip]{A second footnote}
\end{document}
```

This would look the same as above. But note, that the offset could place the note below the text area (but still inside the margin).

See a LaTeX introduction for more information about how to use `\newcommand` to define a command with optional argument.

Comment: Thanks! That seems to work. I thought that the whole reason for using \marginnote was that  \marginpar doesn't do footnotes? I guess it does. Thanks for showing both!

Comment: You are not really using footnotes. For example `\marginpar{\footnote{…}}` or `\footnote{\marginpar{…}}` would not work.

Comment: I will just add here that there is an issue with \marginpar and long notes running off the page (clipping). There is a very easy fix to this that I used: http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/marginfix/marginfix.pdf.